# How to show 3 dots menu on action bar?

Tags: kotlin

I have create a option menu in my activity. But Its not showing 3 dots on some device. How can I show 3 dots on action bar of every device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just put this code in you kotlin activity:

```
val config = ViewConfiguration.get(this)
    val menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration::class.java.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey")
    menuKeyField.isAccessible = true
    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false)
```

I hope this help you.